# JavaScript - Splitting Multiple Return Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, slice

I'm building a filter for a search. Everything worked fine before since we only allowed 1 filter at a time. So I'd get a return like this:

```
var returnVal = "&filterName=filterProperty"
var filterFields = returnVal.split(['=']);
var filterCategory = filterFields[0];
var filterCatSplit = filterCategory.substr(1);
var filterTitle = filterFields[1];

<h4>filter title</h4>
<ul>
    <li>filter one</li>
</ul>
```

i'd just get the returnVal and split it at the '='

Now we're going to allow multiple values and I'm not sure how to get them all onto the page in a nice list. Now, returnVal can look like this:

```
var returnVal = "&sizeFilterName=filterProperty,filterPropery&colorFilterName=filterProperty,filterProperty"
```

I now need this to return like this (or something like this)

```
<h4>Size Filter Name</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Size Filter One</li>
    <li>Size Filter Two etc</li>
</ul>

<h4>Color Filter Name</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Color Filter One</li>
    <li>Color Filter Two etc</li>
</ul>
```

I've never had to split and slice so many variants before. I'm a bit lost. I hope this is enough to get an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try splitting on `&`, then taking each item in that list and splitting on `=` and `,`? And then using the property names to decide where each list of values has to go?

Comment: i thought about it, but that seemed like an inefficient way to do it. like its the 'long way' and not the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `returnVal` to `URLSearchParams()` then `.split()` the value by `","` perform tasks using the returned array

```js
let returnVal = "&sizeFilterName=filterProperty,filterPropery&colorFilterName=filterProperty,filterProperty";
let params = Array.from([...new URLSearchParams(returnVal)]
             , ([key, value]) => [key, value.split(",").filter(Boolean)]);
// do stuff with `params`
params.forEach(([key, value]) => 
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<h4>Size ${key}</h4>
<ul>
    ${value.map(prop => `<li>Color ${prop}</li>`).join("")}
</ul>`)
);
```

Comment: this looks like it'll work. im away from my comp to try but as soon as i get there i will. thanks!

Comment: Just noticed the `Color filterProperty` is running for both lists. One should be 'Size filterProperty' and the other 'Color filterProperty' - I'm going to try to work this out

Comment: @rebel84 Noticed that only upon you mentioning it. Originally did not include the string "Color". You should be able to include and use the index argument of `.map()` to check if "Size" or "Color" is the text set at the element before `prop`